# Detecting composed characters to ignore some of them

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, safari

I am writing a contenteditable-based widget which needs to handle text input on its own. It is fairly easy to deal with both ascii and non-ascii characters with something like this:

```
container_element.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
    if (event.ctrlKey || event.altKey || event.metaKey) {
        return;
    }
    if (event.which != 0 && event.charCode != 0) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var c = String.fromCharCode(event.which);
        handle_character(c);
    }
});
```

Now, if I configure my local system to input non-ascii characters through dead key composition (say, altgr for example), the above fails miserably. Fancy editors like google docs appear to handle this case quite well across a wide range of OSes and browsers without any need for external plugins so, it is clear that it *is* possible from the browser-fired events to detect which character is generated from a composition sequence of dead keys.

However, I have been unable to find out how exactly (not even for a single browser/OS combination, say, Chrome/Linux).

Hence my question: would anyone know how to detect which character is being input from a keypress or keydown handler when we are getting a dead-key composition sequence ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks I'm not the only one looking for it :)
I just found a bunch of events related to composition state that may suits your need. I use it to block keyboard events when i'm in a middle of a composed char. The key is to add a simple :

```
var block = false;
input.addEventListener('compositionstart', function() { block = true; });
input.addEventListener('compositionend', function() { block = false; });
```

and use it later in your code within the input event :

```
input.addEventListener('input', function() {
    if (block) { return; }
    console.log(input.value);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kde4gvxn/1/

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that what I want to do is actually impossible given the current DOM keyboard event API. A detailed description of what needs to done can be found here: http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/blog/browser-input-reading.html

For the lazy, it boils down to creating a hidden textarea that gets the focus and all keyboard events. Composed characters must be detected by parsing the content of the textarea and comparing to its previous value.

Answer (score 1):

In 2023, you can simply use `input` event and check for `event.isComposing` to avoid handling mid-composition characters.

```
input.addEventListener('input', function(event) {
    if (event.isComposing) { return; }
    console.log(input.value);
});
```

Note that if you write in typescript and although `event` is defined as `InputEvent` instance based on [W3C specification](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#input), you'll still need to check it via `instanceof`. Found some answers on why is that the case [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39925) but didn't look too deep to see if they are up-to-date.